# How to add padding inside UITextField using NSLayoutConstraint in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint

I have a subclass of `UIView` in which I have `UITextField` and wants to move placeholder text little right. I am using `NSLayoutConstraint` for setting subviews position and size. I have created `UIView` and adding it as `leftView` of `UITextField` but it crashes stating "The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint". Below is my code :

```
class MasterView: UIView {

let searchTextField = UITextField()
let paddingView = UIView()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    searchTextField.placeholder = "Search videos"
    searchTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    paddingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    searchTextField.leftView = paddingView
    searchTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

    self.addSubview(searchTextField)

}

// Gets called when using storyboard

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20))

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 0.12, constant: 0))

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: paddingView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeadingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: searchTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: paddingView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: searchTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: paddingView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: searchTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 0.12, constant: 0))

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: paddingView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: searchTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))

}
```

}

Answer (score 9):

Proper solution for this problem:

```
@IBDesignable
class FormTextField: UITextField {

  @IBInspectable var paddingLeft: CGFloat = 0
  @IBInspectable var paddingRight: CGFloat = 0

  override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + paddingLeft, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width - paddingLeft - paddingRight, height: bounds.size.height)
  }

  override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return textRect(forBounds: bounds)
  }
}
```

taken from [here](http://www.solutionmyself.com/question/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone)

Comment: Awesome thanks so much! This should be marked as the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

Make UITextField custom class and implement this two method in that class and make your textfield as custom textfield.

```
class customTextField: UITextField {

 override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
  return super.textRectForBounds(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)))
 }

 override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
  return super.editingRectForBounds(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds,  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)))
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let paddingForFirst = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, self.Email_Txt.frame.size.height-5))
Email_Txt.leftView = paddingForFirst
Email_Txt.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode .Always
```

Comment: I want to use NSLayoutConstraint for setting padding view. How can it be done and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will help you

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, self.myTextField.frame.height))
myTextField.leftView = paddingView
myTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write below:- **SWIFT 2.1.1**

```
let tempView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(6, 0, 22, 26))
tempView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
searchTextField.leftView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tempView.frame.size.width, tempView.frame.height)

searchTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
searchTextField.leftView = tempView
```

Answer (score 0):

yon should not set or give constraints to that padding view. remove all constraints of padding view. it's left view of `textfield` so it automatically adjust as per constraint of textfield. And set frame of padding view that what space you expect as padding.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this error **"The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint",** because paddingView is added as left/right view and won't required any constraints.

Note : It is not required to give constraint to a view which is added as a left/right view to `UITextField`. So you just need to set frame of a `paddingView` and assign it to the `leftView`. No need to give constraints to `paddingView`.